# HTML form radio button checked, text area enable using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button, textarea

hello everybody I have a HTML form which POST users inputted data to a php file!!!! but there is this problem I have a radio button which has two options : "Yes" and "No" I need to ask an address from the users if they choose "yes" which means after they checked "Yes" a text area should appear automatically ... I have been searching for this and I found how does it work with JavaScript and other things but I cannot find how to do that with PHP, actually I don't know if it works in PHP!! , here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
app-name : <input type="text" name="appname"><br>
app-value : <input type="text" name="apphajm"><br>
app-parts : <input type="text" name="apppart"><br>
app-address : <input type="text" name="appadress"><br>
app-date : <input type="text" name="apptahye"><br>
app-upload date : <input type="text" name="appupload"><br>
Does it have help? : 
<input type="radio" name="appamsh" value="0">Yes<br>
<?php
if($_POST['appamsh']=='0')
{
echo '<input type="text" name="apptextadd">'.'<br>';
}
?>
<input type="radio" name="appamsh" value="1" checked>No
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the error I get:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: appamsh in C:\wamp\www\testdbx6\input.php on line 18 
Call Stack 
# Time Memory Function Location 
1 0.0002 245752 {main}( ) ..\input.php:0
```

.
thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI the actual error message results from the access of the undefined index `appamsh` in the array `$_POST`. Use `isset($_POST['appamsh'])` for testing before accessing the array index.

Comment: actually I meant ajax :D u r totally right :D but the point is how to do that with html or php if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
app-name : <input type="text" name="appname"><br>
app-value : <input type="text" name="apphajm"><br>
app-parts : <input type="text" name="apppart"><br>
app-address : <input type="text" name="appadress"><br>
app-date : <input type="text" name="apptahye"><br>
app-upload date : <input type="text" name="appupload"><br>
Does it have help? : 
<input type="radio" name="appamsh" value="0">Yes<br>

Whatever label: <input type="text" name="apptextadd" hidden>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="appamsh" value="1" checked>No
</form>
<script>
$('input[name="appamsh"]').on('change', function() {
$('input[name="apptextadd"]').attr('hidden', false).focus();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot I don't really understand where should I put the first part :D but now at least I know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don't use any in PHP for this.  PHP is a script that runs on the server.  It will generate a stream of bytes (HTML in this case) that will be interpreted/run on the browser.

The functionality you want is JavaScript functionality that runs on the browser.  Only JavaScript can be associated with a form input control so as to be active when the user clicks on it.  You use the PHP to generate the JavaScript in the page (just include the JavaScript in the source file) and the JS will then take this action in the browser.

The PHP might be used to include dynamic content into the page (e.g. data read from a database).  But once it gets to the browser it is all HTML with JavaScript.